# ASP.Net Core Web Api not working after calling page published to server

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a relatively simple web api call that sends an email.  everything works fine when I use postman or when I make the call from javascript on an html page running on my computer.  I published the web api to my azure site and the call still works in postman and on the locally running page.  However, I have published the exact html page to 2 different web servers and the email no longer sends.

here is the relevant javascript, the url is obfuscated. I would prefer that it was not public

```
function sendEmail() {
        var uri = "http://mysubdomain.azurewebsites.net/api/shirt";
        //var uri = "https://localhost:44337/api/shirt";
        //alert("hello");
        const email = {
            CustomerName: $('#custName').val(),
            CustomerSchool: $('#custSchool').val(),
            CustomerEmail: $('#custEmail').val(),
            CustomerPhone: $('#custPhone').val(),
            Design: $("input[name='designradios']:checked").val(),
            Mascot: $("input[name='mascotradios']:checked").val(),
            PrimaryColor: $('primColor').val(),
            SecondaryColor: $('secColor').val(),
            TertiaryColor: $('tertColor').val(),
            Font: $("input[name='fontradios]:checked").val()
        }
        //alert(email.CustomerEmail);

        $.ajax({
            url: uri,
            type: "PUT",
            accepts: "application/json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(email),
            success: function (result) {
                //getData();
                //alert(result);
            }

        });
    }
```

Here is the controller method.  If sure there is a better way to do this, and I would be glad to find a better way, but I need something that works.

```
public ActionResult PutShirt([FromServices] IEmailService Mailer,Email email)
    {
        EmailAddress customerEmailAddress = new EmailAddress();
        customerEmailAddress.Name = email.CustomerName;
        customerEmailAddress.Address = email.CustomerEmail;

        EmailAddress catalystEmailAddress = new EmailAddress();
        companyEmailAddress.Name = "Company";
        companyEmailAddress.Address = "info@company.net";

        EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage();
        message.ToAddresses.Add(customerEmailAddress);
        message.ToAddresses.Add(companyEmailAddress);
        message.FromAddresses.Add(companyEmailAddress);

        message.Subject = "test";
        message.Content = "This is a test";

        Mailer.Send(message);

        return StatusCode(200);
        }
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: I am not getting one, the email just doesn't send

Comment: So I added error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
         alert('Error - ' + errorMessage);  and the error I get is "error" that's it

Comment: You can try to [remote debug your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-azure?view=vs-2019#remote_debug_azure_app_service) and troubleshoot the issue with your code.

Comment: I will certainly try it, but I am very confused, because the api works fine after being published, from my home computer (local html or postman) it is only after the html is put on a remote server that things fall apart.

Comment: So it looks like it might be an issue with Cors, but I am having trouble getting that to work as well. any tips?

Comment: Hi @ken.catalyst, to enable CORS for your app on Azure, please refer to my post.

Answer (score 0):

> I have published the exact html page to 2 different web servers and the email no longer sends.
>
> it looks like it might be an issue with Cors, but I am having trouble getting that to work as well

If your back-end service/app is hosting on Azure App Service, you can try to configure and enable CORS for your app on Azure portal, like below.

[image]